# How can I reduce hissing sound produced by pressure cooker?

Tags: kitchen

When I use pressure cooker, hissing sounds are produced and vapour comes out of the vent pipe.

Comment: That might just be the way it’s designed - especially the vapour venting.

Comment: That;s quite normal - so long as you've turned down the heat once it starts hissing, which reduces the noise a bit

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the vent pipe is clean - when it's gets left-overs from previous cooking it starts making more noise - and the noise gets stranger and more high pitched.

Answer (score 1):

To a certain extent, noise is unavoidable.

The pressure cooker **must** be able to vent, to avoid building up too much pressure. It vents through a small hole so it can build up some pressure, this is what makes a pressure cooker work (high pressure means a higher temperature).

If the vent gets larger, you'll get less noise but the pan won't be able to build pressure any more, making it pointless to use one instead of a normal pan.